# Fill in values in excel between 2 numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel

[Enter a stepped average between the 2 number (27 & 10)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtzJ0.jpg)

```
10  0
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
27  10
    11
    12
    13
    14
    15
    16
    17
    18
    19
47  20
    21
    22
    23
    24
    25
    26
    27
    28
    29
72  30
    31
    32
    33
    34
    35
    36
    37
    38
    39
102 40
```

Comment: What Formula you have tried for both 10 and 27 !! Or are you trying Running Average ?

Comment: I have this, but over 2000 cells, wanting to fill in in increments between the 2 cell values every 10 cells

Comment: There's only 8 cells between 10 & 27.  What happened to row 9?  Also, it might be helpful if you show the result you are looking for.

Comment: So Ive updated the following, so at increments of 10, I have a value, here are the first 5, I need the values populated in between (left column)

Comment: Please include some description of the issue in the body of the question itself. Perhaps some context as to "why" may also be helpful to helping us solve this more effectively for you. But you also should show us what you have tried so far. I mean, right now you can just do what you want manually. For 2000 rows that's perhaps an hour's work. So clarifying that you want the process automated would be helpful, as well as listing the things you've tried so far so we either know what not to try, or can point out where you went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This may help you.  If you have two cells in a column with the values 10 and 27 and there are empty cells between them and you wish to fill those cells in a "smooth" fashion:

[image]

Then select the part of the column containing the cells and run this short macro:

```
Sub FillInTheBlanks()
    Dim incr As Double, r As Range, rr As Range

    Set r = Selection
    incr = (r(r.Count) - r(1)) / (r(r.Count).Row - r(1).Row)

    For i = 2 To r.Count - 1
        r(i).Value = r(i).Offset(-1, 0).Value + incr
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: * Gasp * Did Gary's Student not declare `i`? That's impossible! (but you declared the unused variable `rr`).

Comment: @Gary'sStudent,, how would you achieve 10 to 27 to 47 and so on left to the series between 0 to 40 !!

Comment: It's incredible that Excel does not offer this basic functionality.

Comment: @pytago  Perhaps there **is** a native feature.............Consider opening a new question.